# radio button working in google chrome but not in firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, radio-button

in my view,radio button is working in google chrome but not in firefox.please tell me what will be the problem?

view:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"    >
       <input type='radio' name="property" value="1" id="home" >          
       Home
    </button>

   <!--style="background-color: #0eaaa6"-->

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" >
      <input type='radio' name="property" value="2" id="plot" > 
      Plot
   </button>

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" >
      <input type='radio' name="property" value="3" id="commercial" >       
      Commercial
   </button>
```

Comment: Can you provide some snippets of code? Also, what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: <div class="formField" style="margin-left:9px;">
  <label>Purpose</label>
 <div class="btn-group check form-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><input type='radio'  name="purpose_type" value="Sale"> Buy</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><input type='radio'  name="purpose_type" value="Rent"> Rent</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><input type='radio'  name="purpose_type" value="Wanted"> Wanted</button>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: radio button not working means when i click on radio button,it performs no functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is that you've got `input` elements nested inside `button` elements. Strictly speaking, this is not permitted as content inside a `button` element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content).

Firefox, which is more standards-compliant than Chrome, doesn't allow this. There are a number of ways you could hack this, but I highly recommend not using `button` tags. If you need these elements to look like buttons, use CSS.